# maintain older unison 2.40.x via homebrew

Tags: homebrew, unison

I have a perfectly working unsion version (2.48.3) which I installed via homebrew.
So far so good.
But I want to keep a folder in sync with a remote machine on which unison is installed in version 2.40.x.
I do not have root access on this remote machine, therefore I was wondering wether there is a convenient way to also maintain a 2.40.x install on my local machine and I would preferably know wether this can also be mainted by homebrew.

best regards,
khx0

Answer (score 2):

The best way would be to maintain older unison version in the `homebrew-versions` tap.  There is already `unison232`; you could add a `unison240`.

Comment: Okay I will try my best to do so. I had a look at the unison232.rb formulae in the homebrew/versions repo. I can change the url to the 2.40.x version which I like, that seems easy so far. But how do I figure out wether the remaining installation steps and dependencies work the same way.